# err_too_many_redirects and This page isn’t working in laravel my middleware

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-middleware

i have two users who i have two role normal user and debtor user. i want what to prevent the debtor user from accessing normal user dashboard . i have created debtors dashboard too.below is what i have tried.how can i archive this.

this is my web.php

```
////// User debtors Authentications ///////////
   Route::middleware(['debtors'])->group(function(){//debtors routes will goes here
      Route::get('/debtors/home', 'HomeController@kfsdebtors_form');
      Route::get('/debtors/kfsdebtors_form', 'HomeController@defaultersdashboard');
      Route::get('/debtors/applications_dashboard', 'HomeController@applications_dashboard');
      Route::get('/debtors/manage_debt', 'HomeController@manage_debt');
      Route::post('/debtors/manage_debt', 'HomeController@transaction');
      Route::get('/debtors/manage_debt', 'HomeController@defaulters');
      Route::get('/debtors/view_transaction', 'HomeController@view_transaction');
      Route::post('/debtors/view_transaction', 'HomeController@view_transaction');
      // Route::get('/user/{data}', 'UserController@getData');
        // Route::post('/user/{data}', 'UserController@postData');
   });
   //  Route::group(['middleware' => 'debtors'], function () {
   //      Route::get('/debtors/home/kfsdebtors_form', 'HomeController@kfsdebtors_form');
   //      Route::get('/debtors/applications_dashboard', 'HomeController@applications_dashboard');
   //      Route::get('/debtors/manage_debt', 'HomeController@manage_debt');
   // });
////// User normal user Authentications ///////////
    Route::middleware(['normal_user'])->group(function(){
       Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
       Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@balance');
    });

    // Route::group(['middleware' => 'is.admin'], function () {
    //     Route::get('/user/{data}', 'UserController@getData');
    //     Route::post('/user/{data}', 'UserController@postData');
    // });
Route::get('/register_sawmill', 'Auth\register_sawmill@create')->name('register_sawmill');
Route::post('/register_sawmill', 'Auth\register_sawmill@register');
Route::get('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout', function () {
```

this is my middleware for debtors.php

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::user()->debtor == 1)
        {
            return $next($request);
        }

        return redirect()->guest('/debtors/home');
    }
}
```

this is normal_user.php middleware

````
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // if(Auth::check()) {
        //   if(Auth::user()->debtor == 0) {
        //     return $next($request);
        //   }
        // }

        // return redirect('/home');
        // if(!Auth::check() || Auth::user()->debtor != '0'){
        //     return redirect()->route('/debtors/home');
        // }
        // return $next($request);


        if(Auth::check()) {
          if(Auth::user()->debtor == 0) {
            return $next($request);
          }
        }

        return redirect('/debtor/home');
    }
```
````

Comment: you don't need to two middleware just one will do

Comment: @AdityaThakur how will i archive that

Comment: In your debtors middleware you redirect to an route that also have Debtors middleware, this will cause an infinite loop redirecting to the same route.

Comment: how should i redirect correctly

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change `return redirect('/home');`

and redirect to a simple page, like `return redirect('/register_sawmill');`

the problem I think, is that the normal user middleware check if the user is authenticated, if not, it should redirect to some page that is not maintained by the middleware

Comment: it is saying ```Route [/register_sawmill] not defined.```

Comment: try with some route that you are it exist, or if you can screen the error for us

Comment: @Mehidi wait i update the question on the changes i have made

Comment: of course you'll get 404 error, cause you have no route assiciated to `'/debtor/home'`. you should redirect to the login page instead of a url that is maintained by the same middleware.

Comment: How will I do it because I have tried so many methods  and it's not working still please help

Comment: create a login page with a login route, and redirect to it

Comment: so use `redirect('/login')` inside the middlewares